# Swap high part of a byte with low part in assembly for 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I need rotate hight part with low part in Byte, i have in AL=[0101 0000] and i want AL=[0000 0101].

```
mov al, 01010000b ;Al=01010000
shr 4, al
```

but i have erro A2001: immediate operand not allowed

Comment: you want `ror al, 4`

Comment: @MichaelPetch This gives: error A2070: invalid instruction operands

Comment: What assembler are you using and what processor are you targetting?

Comment: I'm assuming MASM from the error, but hard to tell what processor you are assembling for.

Comment: @MichaelPetch masm611

Comment: At the top of your assembly file try putting `.186` (Yes there is a period in front)

Comment: The other option is `mov cl, 4` `ror al, cl`

Comment: erro a2001: immediate operand not allowed

Comment: You sure you have the order correct? I didn't say `ror 4, al` I said `ror al, 4` They are not the same. The destination is the left operand.

Comment: ITS WORKSSSSS THANKS!!!